# ItemsControl Not Showing Up: XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

so I've made a really simply ItemsControl in Visual Studio but its not showing up. There are no errors in my text or anything. Here's the XAML:

```
       <ItemsControl x:Name="ToDoItemTemplate" Margin="129,168,640,332" AutomationProperties.Name="" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Background="#FFB8A91A">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#FFCDC51E">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="mainTitle" Text="{Binding ItemTitle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="842,356,398,257"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And here's the c#:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        List<ToDoItem> items = new List<ToDoItem>();
        items.Add(new ToDoItem() { ItemTitle = NameBox.Text });
        items.Add(new ToDoItem() { ItemTitle = "Learn C#" });
        items.Add(new ToDoItem() { ItemTitle = "Wash the car" });

        ToDoItemTemplate.ItemsSource = items;
    }
    public class ToDoItem
    {
        public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of those margins. You don't need RenderTransformOrigin either since there's no RenderTransform. And the DataContext makes no sense. Remove that too.

Comment: IF you loading data via codebehind the Datacontext is probably hurting you as @Ed has indicated.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks! worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all those margins. They'll make a mess of everything. I've found it easiest and most maintainable to do XAML layout with StackPanel, Grid, and so on.

You don't need RenderTransformOrigin either since there's no RenderTransform.

And the DataContext makes no sense. I'd advise you to remove that as well.